# Join referenced property on joined collection element

Tags: c#, hibernate, join, nhibernate, queryover

I have `users` and `users_updateable_data` tables which have 1-to-1 relationship (`User.UpdateableData`). Also each `User` can be in a `Guild` (there is a mapped `Guild.Users`; `User.GuildId` property is a foreign key for `guilds`).

So I have `Guild, Guild.Users, User, User.UpdateableData, User.GuildId`.

I'm trying to get specific properties from `users` which meet some criteria:

```
    public class UserTournamentInfo
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; } // from user
        public virtual int TournamentXP { get; set; } // from upd. data
        public virtual int League { get; set; } // from user
        public virtual int TournamentClassXP { get; set; } // from upd. data
        public virtual int? GuildId { get; set; } // from user
        public virtual int? GuildLeague { get; set; } // from guild
    }
```

So I need to make two joins: guild + users (right outer) and user + upd. data.

This is how I tried to do it:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserTournamentInfo> GetTournamentUserToXP()
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            User userAlias = null;
            User.UpdateableDataContainer userUpdAlias = null;
            Guild guildAlias = null;
            UserTournamentInfo dto2 = null;

            var result = session.QueryOver<Guild>(() => guildAlias)
                .JoinAlias(x => x.Users, () => userAlias, JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
                // next line doesn't compile
                .JoinAlias((User u) => u.UpdateableData, () => userUpdAlias, JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
                .Select(MakeProjections())
                .Where(() => userAlias.TournamentXP > 0)
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserTournamentInfo>())
                .List<UserTournamentInfo>();

            session.Transaction.Commit();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I define the projections:

```
    public static IProjection[] MakeProjections()
    {
        Guild guildAlias = null;
        User userAlias = null;
        User.UpdateableDataContainer userUpdAlias = null;
        UserTournamentInfo dto = null;

        return new[]
                {
     Projections.Property(() => userAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.Id),
     Projections.Property(() => userUpdAlias.TournamentClassXP).WithAlias(() => dto.TournamentClassXP),
     Projections.Property(() => userUpdAlias.TournamentXP).WithAlias(() => dto.TournamentXP),
     Projections.Property(() => userAlias.GuildId).WithAlias(() => dto.GuildId),
     Projections.Property(() => userAlias.League).WithAlias(() => dto.League),
     Projections.Property(() => guildAlias.League).WithAlias(() => dto.GuildLeague),
                      };
    }
```

It worked before I decided to split `users` into two tables - `users` and `users_updateable_data`.

How to make this join query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with HQL:

```
SELECT 
u.Id as Id, ud.TournamentClassXP as TournamentClassXP, ud.TournamentXP as TournamentXP, u.GuildId as GuildId, u.League as League, g.League as GuildLeague
FROM Guild g RIGHT OUTER JOIN g.Users u JOIN u.UpdateableData ud
WHERE ud.TournamentXP > 0
```